# Newbie setting up eclipse. How do I add java IDE to a c++/c packaged version of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to eclipse, perfer netbeans actually, but android tutorials use eclipse.

The eclipse website is a mess and just confuses me. What projects do I need to install to have the same functionality as the eclipse package for java devs.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend downloading a [classic package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (bottom of the page). Or you could add JDT to your version.

Comment: The problem was that when I go to the download link on JDT I get taken to this huge downloads page. Please eclipse just link to the damn file, not the entire repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **EPP Packages Repository** in Eclipse to install the **EPP Java Package**.
It's the same package as proposed on the Eclipse Download page but it will download only the required files.

The Update site URL for EPP Packages for Galileo is :
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo